# Passing props from Container to mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to access a Container's props (that were passed in from Redux state) from within mapDispatchToProps (mDTP). My container is responsible for dispatching an action to fetch data, but the action that it dispatches needs access to a piece of redux state. That state will be used as a field in the HTTP header.

The redux state that I am trying to access is **languages**. I want to then pass it in as a header to mDTP

Here is my container:

```
const ExperienceListContainer = ({ list, loading, failed, readList, languages }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    readList()
  }, [])

  const apiRequestParams = {
    endpoint: 'GetToursByCity',
    count: 10,
    step: 10,
    cityid: 'e2e12bfe-15ae-4382-87f4-88f2b8afd27a',
    startdate: '2018-12-20 8:30:00',
    enddate: '2018-12-20 22:15:00',
    sort_by: 'rating',
    guests: 10,
    min_price: 1,
    max_price: 100.50,
    time_of_day: 1,
    sort_by: 'rating',
    categories: '',
    languages: languages
  }

  return <ExperienceList {...{ list, loading, failed, languages }} />
}

ExperienceListContainer.propTypes = {
  list: T.arrayOf(T.object).isRequired,
  limit: T.number,
  loading: T.bool,
  failed: T.bool,
  readList: T.func.isRequired,
  filter: T.shape({
    interests: T.arrayOf(T.shape({
      id: T.number.isRequired,
      text: T.string.isRequired
    })),
    languages: T.arrayOf(T.shape({
      id: T.number.isRequired,
      text: T.string.isRequired
    })),
  }),
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return (
    ({
      list: state.resource.experiences,
      languages: state.filter.languages
    })
  )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  readList: () => {
    return (
      dispatch(resourceListReadRequest('experiences', { apiRequestParams }))
    )
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExperienceListContainer)
```

The problem with this current code is that mDTP cannot access *apiRequestParams*. It is undefined as far as it is concerned.

Based on my research, the answers that pop up are to use mergeProps (as an arg passed into connect()) and ownProps (a param included with mapDispatchToProps), but neither of these seem to be working, at least in the way I'm implementing them. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass them to readList as a parameter to access them like this:
      readList(apiParams)
And use them like this: 
     readList: apiRequestParams  => {
         return (
             dispatch(resourceListReadRequest('experiences', { 
             apiRequestParams }))
         )
This is because apiRequestParams is local to the container itself and cannot be access outside of the component.

You would also have to declare it above the useEffect and pass it as parameter to the useEffect so that it gets evaluates, if the language changes for example and keep the reference with useRef or declare it within the useEffect so that you don't cause an infinity loop.

Hope that helps. Happy coding.